# Gradle project with two Android Application modules

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to configure two android application modules within a single gradle project.

- app
- tools

App should be completely unaware of tools, while tools should be able to access all of the classes and resources of App.

The Idea is to have app as an android application and tools as another android applications that "extends" app.

The key point is that App's code should not be touched, not even the gradle file.

What I tried so far:

I defined tools depending on app, tool's build.gradle is this one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':app')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

In the manifest of tools I am trying to start an activity of app, but when I run tools the result is this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tools/com.example.app.activities.WannaRunActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.app.activities.WannaRunActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tools.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.tools, /system/lib]]
```

How would you do this?

Comment: It's a strange configuration. It would be better to use "app" as a library project to use as core and then build other two modules: one simple as a "wrapper" only and the second with the extension capabilities.

Comment: I know it is, but I must keep app as it is, and app is under version control while tools is not. The Idea is that a C.I. system should be able to compile app alone without even seeing anything related to tools. And I need app to be an application itself.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to do this kind of extension, so I'd think to a different solution as cloning the code of "app", I know it's ugly but if you can't touch "app" I don't see any other solution.

Comment: Would it be possible to have tools itself as a library project and compile it "on demand"? this way I would be able to merge its manifest with app manifest but only if app was built along with tools

Comment: Mmmm...maybe you can go with that. At the moment I can't see drawbacks, usually you have the opposite case, however you can try.

Comment: There is a way to do that on command line? It's working if I add a compile dependency in app gradle file pointing to tools gradle file but I would like to do this only if requested explicitly to gradle. `compile project(':tools')`

Answer (score 2):

Seems  like a case for ProductFlavors[1].

Single application module with all your 'app' functionality under `src/main` and add a new product flavor for tools - `src/tools`.

Then by building the 'tools' flavor you get access to the functionality in 'app' while adding the functionality for 'tools'.

```
productFlavors {
    tools {
        packageName "com.example.tools"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    tools.java.srcDirs = ['src/tools/java']
    tools.resources.srcDirs = ['src/tools/resources']
}
```

The tools source code will be added to the 'app' code when the tools build is run. You can also override the code under `src/main` if you need to.

[1] android gradle documentation - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

[2] Build Variants documentation - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

Comment: In fact, I could use product flavour but I want to be even less invasive on the build file (Also because I already use the flavours) so I came up with another solution that I will eventually post here.